# Scrollable sidebar with footer visible if the main content is short

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-4

I'm building a page with Bootstrap 4.

Now when I open my page the footer is under the viewport, hidden away.

**I need to have a footer visible when the main content is short**.

Instead, when the main content is longer than the viewport, the footer should act normally (the default behavior: I can scroll the page normally).

The sidebar needs to change is height according to whether the main content is short or long, so according to whether the footer is visible or not.

The sidebar need to stay "sticky" if I scroll especially if the main content is longer than sidebar's one.

Is that possible?

### My reproduction: https://codepen.io/fredhors/pen/oNgzoyR

[image]

### Code:

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 2.5rem
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 2.5rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 2.5rem);
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  /* margin-top: 5rem; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="all">

  <div class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand">Navbar</div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="sidebar">
          <h3>Sidebar</h3>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
          <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <h3>Main</h3>
          <p>The problem I have is I need the footer visible until the main content increase in height.</p>
          <p>Now it appears if you scroll only.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add height:100% (`h-100`) to make the container and row consume full height of main which which will allow the sidebar and content to scroll as needed. It would work like this...

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand">Navbar</div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="sidebar h-100">
                    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="col h-100 overflow-auto">
                    <h3>Main</h3>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/EbCKdzQhIQ/bootstrap-sidebar-sticky-footer)

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks. But this is not what I need. I need the Footer to be visible just if the main content is short.

Comment: If the main content is long I want Footer to be under the viewport, the standard way.

Comment: but you want the sidebar to scroll?

Comment: Yes. Why, it is a problem?

Comment: I updated the demo: https://www.codeply.com/p/EbCKdzQhIQ .. is that what you expect?

Comment: Very close to what I want.But still not there. I need the Sidebar to stay "sticky" when I scroll the main content. Especially if the main content is longer than the sidebar one.

Comment: In your updated example if I scroll the page the sidebar scrolls too.

Comment: Yes, that what the image you posted shows too. There's no way to only have the sidebar *not* scroll when scrolling the body. It could work if you let the main scroll instead of the body, but then the footer will always be visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204263/discussion-between-fred-hors-and-zim).

Comment: I updated the question with the sidebar sticky spec.

Comment: I read your updated comment. Oh, you are amazing and if for you there is not solution I think this is really the true. Are you sure? Can i change something to accomplish this?

Comment: I found this page: https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/. I need something like that. But with footer to be visible only if main content short.